# where to find "blobs name" and "containername" on MS Azure storage

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-blob-storage

I have created a "blobs" storage on MS cloud and when I tried to read data from it to Jupyter notebook for some analysis which according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob#load-the-data-into-a-pandas-dataframe), it requires "container_name" as well as "blob_name". But when I created the storage, as far as I remember I didn't come across the step where I had to assign the blob name. However, apparently I needed it. Unfortunately, so far I couldn't find it but I believed that I could guess the "container_name". I did a quick research on google but couldn't find any resources that says exactly where it is. So, I would like to know how I can find out the "container_name" as well as "blob_name" from the MS Azure panel.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access them via your **storage account** in the [**azure portal**](https://portal.azure.com), refer to the screenshot.

[image]

Choose a container, you could see the blobs, including names, blob type, size,etc.

[image]

Comment: thx for your reply. However, I believe that would to [this](https://i1.wp.com/d365blogger.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/3.jpg?resize=578%2C455&ssl=1) which under name column I believe that it is the "blob name"/"container" name. I still can't figure out where the blob name will be.

Comment: @bensw You should choose a container, then you will see the blobs in the container. You could see my update.

Comment: Yes, I saw my files but I'm looking for "blob name". So, I can read them to jupyter notebook as it mentions in the document I put in my question.

Comment: @bensw The files in the `container` are all called `blob`, the blob you are looking for is your specific value, I will not know which one. About blob storage, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).

Comment: Okay. Thank you @Joy Wang. That's kinda makes sense. Let me test it if it works I'll come back and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @bensw I have read the article you mentioned, you may do the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob#prerequisites), and just find the blob you used to store the data.

Comment: admittedly, I misunderstood and thought that it would read data without downloading it. Sorry for the confusion.